# Read lines up to a pattern

Tags: ruby

I am trying to read file contents up to a pattern.

**Example: Input.txt**

```
#random
[groups]
earth = id\check_id, mars_nedr, id\npo0md, id\cfrtyh
mars = id\koi8khl, id\xzlo09, id\kzlop0
venus= id\vyu890, id\zzgy78, id\jz9lop

[/]

read = check
write =@mars
```

I need the data between `[groups]` and `[/]` to get an array or a hash and ignore the rest. I tried the following:

```
text = File.open('input.txt', 'r')
text.each_line do |line|
  next if line.start_with? '#'
  puts line unless (line=="\[\/\]")
end
```

But it prints the entire file contents. Any help will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
state = false
File.new("input.txt").each do |line|
  state = true if line.start_with?("[groups]")
  next unless state
    ... # do_something
  break if line.start_with?("[/]")
end
```

Comment: `each.reduce(false)`?

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect use-case for Ruby famous [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/):

```
File.open('input.txt', 'r').each_line do |line|
  line = line.strip
  next unless (line == '[groups]')..(line == '[/]')
  puts line
end
```

Comment: Famous? I don't think so. It's barely known :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't beat the flip-flop solution from mudasobwa but here is an simple alternative with split using regular expressions.
It produces a hash like asked.

```
Hash[*(File.read('./input.txt').split(/\[|\]/)[2].strip.split(/=|\n/))]
```

gives

```
# {"earth "=>" id\\check_id, mars_nedr, id\\npo0md, id\\cfrtyh", "mars "=>" id\\koi8khl, id\\xzlo09, id\\kzlop0", "venus"=>" id\\vyu890, id\\zzgy78, id\\jz9lop"}
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternate option

Answer (score 0):

1. You don’t need **next** after #, right? It has to be next after ‘[group]’
2. You need to ‘break’ loop if you reached some end condition, but currently you just not printing it and moving to the next line

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick:

```
start_interpreter = false
myhash = {}

File.open('input.txt', 'r') do |infile|
  while (line = infile.gets)
    if !(line =~ /\[groups\]/).nil?
      start_interpreter = true
      next
    end
    break if !(line =~ /\[\/\]/).nil?
    if start_interpreter
      split_line = line.split('=')
      myhash[split_line[0]] = split_line[1]
    end
  end
end

p myhash
```