# Counting changes in an array

Tags: ruby, counter

I would like to count the number of times `"red"` is followed by `"green"` in this array:

```
["red", "orange", "green", "red", "yellow", "blue", "green"]
```

If it is another color, the code should ignore it and proceed to the next item in the array.

```
event_type.each_slice(2) do |red, green|
  break unless green
  count = count + 1
end

p "The count is #{count}"
```

Step 1:

```
Look for red
```

Step 2:

```
IF not last item 
           Compare with next item on array
ELSE       Go to Step 4
```

Step 3:

```
IF green, count = count + 1
          Go to Step 1
ELSE      Go to Step 2
```

Step 4:

```
Print Count
```

Comment: If green followed by red then count is 1?

Comment: are looking for the cases red followed by green or what?

Comment: @RAJ If red to green dont count as 1

Comment: This will always evaluate to `event_type.length/2`. On line 2, when you say `break unless green`, `green` is a string. Strings always evaluate to true. Therefore `count` will be incremented on every iteration.

Comment: @marmeladze Yes, looking for red to green. It will not reset if orange appears.

Comment: so array you've provided has 2 cases right?

Comment: @marmeladze yes. the count should be 2

Comment: Why is the count 2? The first `"red"` changes to `"orange"` and the second one changes to `"yellow"`. Neither changes to `"green"` and according to the question _"If it is another color, the code would ignore it"_.

Comment: @Stefan IF it is red it will look for green. IF the second is orange, it would ignore that color and continue looking for green.

Comment: Could you explain the algorithm step by step? What I see is `"red"` followed by (or changing to) `"orange"`, followed by `"green"` and so on.

Comment: @Stefan Hi Stefan, I've written the steps on my question.

Comment: Stefan, he is possibly looking for event chains in arbitrary length  that occurs between red and green.

Comment: I expect the downvotes and votes to close are largely attributable to your phrase '"red" changes to "green"', which makes no sense. If you wish to count the number of times '"red" is followed by "green"', you need to edit your question and make that change.

Comment: Looking over the answers I see that's what you want, so it reads fine now. I deleted my last comment.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below one is solution I believe. Sure there is more room to refactor it, you can start from here.

```
a = ["red", "orange", "green", "red", "yellow", "blue", "green"]    
a.reject {|e| !['red', 'green'].include? e }
  .each_cons(2)
  .select{|e| e == ['red', 'green']}
  .size
```

A more artistic version.

```
def neither_red_nor_green e
  !['red', 'green'].include? e
end

def red_followed_by_green ary
  ary == ['red', 'green']
end

a.reject(&method(:neither_red_nor_green))
  .each_cons(2)
  .select(&method(:red_followed_by_green))
  .size
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Stefan for below suggestions.

```
def either_red_or_green e
  ['red', 'green'].include? e
end

def red_followed_by_green ary
  ary == ['red', 'green']
end


a.select(&method(:either_red_or_green))
  .each_cons(2)
  .count(&method(:red_followed_by_green))
```

**UPDATE**

As Stefan Pochmann proposed,

```
a.select(&method(:either_red_or_green))
  .each_cons(2)
  .count(['red', 'green'])
```

will do the same work, without needing another method call.

Comment: where should I add my count to print it out?

Comment: You can use `select { condition }` instead of `reject { !condition }` and `count { condition }` instead of `select { condition }.size`

Comment: sorry but could you point out which line that outputs the count?

Comment: check ruby documentation - https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: If my `a` is a nested array, [color, time]. How would I select the color to do comparison?  I tried changing `a.select(&method(:either_red_or_green))` to `"#a[0]".select(&method(:either_red_or_green))` it doesnt work, may I ask for your suggestion?

Comment: How about `count(['red', 'green'])` ?

Comment: Just another variation: configuration `ends = ["red", "green"]` followed by `a.select { |x| ends.include? x }.each_cons(2).count(ends)`

Comment: @marmeladze `a.map(&:first)` doesnt work. Result: `"red",  "green" = 1` `"red", "orange", "green" = 0`

Comment: possibly you are missing something - [have a look up this](https://repl.it/@marmeladze1/CleverSorrowfulAssociate)

Answer (score 7):

This is a perfect use-case for Ruby famous [flip-flop](http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/):

```
input = %w[red orange green red yellow blue green]

input.reduce(0) do |count, e|
  if (e == "red")..(e == "green") and (e == "green")
    count + 1  # inc on right boundary
  else
    count
  end
end
#⇒ 2
```

Also tested on

```
%w[yellow green green red orange green red yellow blue green red yellow]
```

<sub>FWIW, this is a second question I answered suggesting the flip-flop in a week. The previous [one is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665714/2035262).</sub>

---

**Clean solution from Stefan Pochmann**

```
input.count { |x| x == "green" if (x == "red")..(x == "green") }
```

Comment: Coincidence! I maintain that this operator is barely known. Kudos for popularizing it, though.

Comment: Something is bugging me about your usage of flip-flop here, but I having troubling pinning it down...

Comment: This code counts incomplete sequences. If your input ends with `red yellow yellow`, it will count it (it shouldn't)

Comment: Nah, it doesn't look like flip-flop should be used here at all. Doesn't handle edge conditions well. I like @marmeladze's answer better.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure it does, flip-flop is to skip multiple left boundaries, and here it does it’s job perfectly. I have it fixed, btw. You like other answers more because you like Rails :-P

Comment: Yep, with this edit it works better, but look at all this extra cruft. It is _hardly_ a "perfect use-case", would you agree? It would be, if the loop body was a nice and clean `foo if a..b` :trollface:

Comment: This accumulator juggling completely obscures the purpose, imho. You now have to write documentation to explain what this does. (which you did already)

Comment: "in a week" - JFYI, that one was exactly _two_ weeks ago. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it’s so-called “relativistic” week.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev one more edit: are you now satisfied with how it does not obscure anything? :)

Comment: Have you tried competing in logical obfuscation contexts? You have great potential. :trollface: This code easily generates two [WTFs](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m). Good exercise, yes, but I wouldn't put this into production code. I'm too dumb to understand it later :)

Comment: Mind you, this is still  better than anything I have (that isn't a copy of marmeladze's answer). :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure I have; basically I am having tried competing in logical obfuscation contexts 40hrs/week :)

Comment: Ah, that was supposed to be "contest", btw. Noticed it just now.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for pointing out the use of Flip Flop. Is it possible to use it for nested arrays? for eg, [color, time] the occurrence from red to green should be within 10 seconds

Comment: @JoshuaNg I am not sure I follow. Flip-flop is all about booleans, is has nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: @mudasobwa ah I see

Comment: @JoshuaNg the same applies here. if you want to use that solution (which is really sexy) change `input.reduce(0)` to `input.map(&:first).reduce(0)`

Comment: @marmeladze or just `input.reduce(0) { |acc, (e, _)| ...}` to avoid redundant mapping.

Comment: @marmeladze, mudasobwa, but you're ignoring the time part here. Instead Joshua wants to further filter the matches (count only those flips that happened within 10 seconds, I think). It is definitely out of scope here, though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You said you want a nice and clean `foo if a..b` body? No problem: `input.count { |x| x == "green" if (x == "red")..(x == "green") }`

Comment: @StefanPochmann after 10+ years of Ruby I have no idea why or how that works.

Comment: Just read the linked post and it's awesome. I wish I remember to use it for something one day, if not for efficient clean code, at least to confuse the heck out of the colleagues.

Comment: According to http://chrisseaton.com/rubytruffle/flip-flops/ at the time of writing the flipflop was used in only 8 out of all gems.

Comment: @KimmoLehto I wonder how he counted them... anyway, yeah, flip-flop is neat, I don't know why apparently only few people know/like it. It's one of the few things I remember from learning Perl about 18 years ago and I was delighted to learn that Ruby has it, too.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yup, you are right! I guess I will ask a separate question as it involves nested arrays.

Comment: @JoshuaNg: try to solve it yourself first, though. Great learning potential there.

Answer (score 2):

```
count, _ =
["red", "orange", "green", "red", "yellow", "blue", "green"]
.inject([0, nil]) do |(count, state), word|
  if word == "red"
    state = :red
  elsif word == "green" and state == :red
    state = nil
    count += 1
  end
  [count, state]
end
count # => 2
```

Comment: Fun little variations combining count and state: https://eval.in/960310 and https://eval.in/960317

Answer (score 1):

```
def count_red_to_green(arr)
  count = 0
  unmatched_red = false
  arr.each do |colour|
    case colour
    when "red"
      unmatched_red = true
    when "green"
      if unmatched_red
        count += 1
        unmatched_red = false
      end
    end
  end
  count
end

count_red_to_green ["red", "orange", "green", "red", "yellow", "blue", "green"]
  #=> 2
```